# Expression "value.get()" returns multiple of the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

for the bellow code, on the `findspec` command, I am trying to return only the file path and directory names of what the user types in. IF no file exists, "File not Found" is displayed.

This is the part That is not working:

```
def findspec():
    r1 = tar.get()
    rootdir = '.'
    for dirname, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):
        for file in filelist:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, tar.get()):
                list1.insert(END, dirname + "--->" + str(r1))
            else:
                list1.insert(END, "File not found")
```

It should be returning this:

```
User/%User%/directory ---> config.py
User/%User%/directory/static ---> config.py
```

Instead it returns this:

```
File not FOund
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
User/%User%/directory ---> config.py
File not Found
File not Found
User/%User%/directory/static ---> config.py
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
File not Found
```

The source code is below:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from difflib import get_close_matches

def searchdir():
    rootdir = '.'
    for dirname, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):
        for fname in filelist:
            list1.insert(END, dirname +  '\t%s' % fname)

def findspec():
    r1 = tar.get()
    rootdir = '.'
    for dirname, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):
        for file in filelist:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, tar.get()):
                list1.insert(END, dirname + "--->" + str(r1))
            else:
                list1.insert(END, "File not found")

w=Tk()

b1 = Button(w, text="Search", command=findspec)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

tar=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(w, textvariable=tar)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4)

b2 = Button(w, text="Start", command=searchdir)
b2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

#listbox
list1=Listbox(w, height=17, width=75, selectmode=EXTENDED)
list1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=7, columnspan=4, sticky=(N, S, E), pady=5, padx=5)

sb1=Scrollbar(w)
sb1.grid(row=2, column=4, rowspan=7, sticky='nsw', pady=5)
list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

sb2=Scrollbar(w, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sb2.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='esw', padx=5)
list1.configure(xscrollcommand=sb2.set)
sb2.configure(command=list1.xview)

list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')

if __name__=='__main__':
    w.mainloop()
```

Am I doing something wrong, am I just missing something, or other?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This line will give you a syntax error: `r1 = tar.get())`.

Comment: If it should, it does not.

Comment: they just mean that there is a typo (an extra paren `'))'`) on closing the `get()` method call. It probably doesn't exist in the code you are running, but may have been accidentally included when you pasted the code into the question

Comment: ahh, I see that now, thank you.

Comment: it needs to be fixed in the question.

Comment: Fixed, is that why I was downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for file in filelist:` is going to perform the `if/else` check for every file in the `filelist`. But it seems you want to execute the `else` clause not every time that `fnmatch.fnmatch()` fails, but instead only when the search is exhausted and no results have been added to the list, hence when `len(filelist) < 1`:

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, r1):
    list1.insert(END, dirname + "--->" + str(r1))
elif list1.size() < 1:
    list1.insert(END, "File not found")
```

Comment: the first part works like a charm, Thank you! however, the second part does not. It does not display the "File not Found" value.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Sorry I misunderstood that `list1` is a Tkinter Listbox. I've updated the code to use `size()` method.